# What does "=>{}" mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

Can someone kindly explain in simple terms what `=>{}` means in JavaScript?
I have tried googling it but I kept getting irrelevant responses.

For example:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
    .then(response =>{})
  }
```

Comment: It's just an empty function that does nothing.

Comment: `response` is the function arg and `{}` is the function body. This function does nothing. It's an arrow function without any logic or return value. Written another way, it would be `function() {}`

Comment: You're the best Jonathan. Thanks a lot!